# I'm making quicksort in C and can't see what's wrong

Tags: c, crash, quicksort

I'm trying to make quicksort in C for practice, it is crashing and I can't see why.

The code i have so far (it's just the part with throwing numbers higher than pivot on one side and smaller than pivot on the other side + it's only sorting "array"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRSZ 10 //ARRay SiZe

int array[ARRSZ];

void quicksort(int start, int end){
    int pivot = start + (end - start)/2;

    for(int i = start; i < pivot; i++){
        if(array[i] > pivot){
            int x = array[i];
            for(int j = i; i < pivot; j++){
                array[j] = array[j+1];
            }
            array[pivot] = x;
            pivot--;
        }
    }

    printf("\nqs first half\n\n"); //I put these here afterwards so I could see how far the program got.

    for(int i = end; i > pivot; i--){
        if(array[i] < pivot){
            int x = array[i];
            for(int j = i; i > pivot; j--){
                array[j] = array[j-1];
            }
            array[pivot] = x;
            pivot++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRSZ; i++){
        array[i] = rand() % (ARRSZ*2) + 1 - ARRSZ; //Wanted to have numbers form -ARRSZ to +ARRSZ
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\nbreak\n\n");

    quicksort(0, ARRSZ-1);

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRSZ; i++){
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It allways reaches the **"printf("\nbreak\n\n");"** (line 46)
and sometimes the **"printf("\nqs first half\n\n");"** (line 23).

Then windows says that it stopped working and the output says:

*Process returned: -1073741795 (0xC000001D)*

I'm using CodeBlocks 17.12, Windows 7 Pro if it helps.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: you're using `pivot` as *both* an index *and* a value for element comparison. One of those is *wrong*, and in so being, breaks your partition algorithm.

Comment: To expand on that, `array[i] > pivot` should be `array[i] > array[pivot]`

Comment: ^^^ twice, in fact. The second half of your partition code has the same problem.

Comment: Quicksort is suppose swap elements, not shift arrays. The pivot should be a value (pivot = array[start + (end-start)/2] ). The Wiki article has [example code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) .

Answer (score 1):

FOR PARTITION FUNTION you can use following algorithm has hint:

```
template <class DataType>
void partition(DataType theArray[], int first, int last,
            int &pivotIndex) {

   int pIndex = choosePivot(theArray, first, last);

   // put pivot at position first
   swap(theArray[pIndex], theArray[first]);

   DataType pivot = theArray[first]; // copy pivot
int lastS1 = first;           // index of last item in S1
   int firstUnknown = first + 1; //index of 1st item in unknown

   // move one item at a time until unknown region is empty
   for (; firstUnknown <= last; ++firstUnknown) {
      if (theArray[firstUnknown] < pivot)          
         ++lastS1;
         swap(theArray[firstUnknown], theArray[lastS1]);
   }

   // place pivot in proper position and mark its location
   swap(theArray[first], theArray[lastS1]);
   pivotIndex = lastS1;
}
```

QUICK SORT function you can use following algorithm has hint to write the code:

```
void quicksort(DataType theArray[], int first, int last) {

   int pivotIndex;
   if (first < last) {

      partition(theArray, first, last, pivotIndex);

      // sort regions S1 and S2
      quicksort(theArray, first, pivotIndex-1);
      quicksort(theArray, pivotIndex+1, last);
   }
}
```

if you still confused about something you are free to ask in comments